# Как через цикл обойти вокруг ячейки в двумерном массиве?

Tags: java

Как можно изменить значения в массиве `char[][]` вокруг ячейки (8 соседних ячеек) учитывая проверку выхода за границы массива?

Comment: А что Вас смущает, если понятие цикла уже знакомо?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Обход восьми соседних ячеек

```
char[][] array = ...
int i0 = ...
int j0 = ...

int height = array.length;
int width = array[0].length;
for (int i = i0 - 1; i <= i0 + 1; ++i) {
    for (int j = j0 - 1; j <= j0 + 1; ++j) {
        // проверка на выход за границы массива
        // и проверка на то, что обрабатываемая ячейка не равна изначальной ячейке
        if (0 <= i && i < height && 0 <= j && j < width && (i != i0 || j != j0)) {
            // любая операция с соседним элементом
            array[i][j]++;
        }
    }
}
```

### Обход четырёх соседних ячеек

Можно добавить в предыдущий способ проверку на то, что ячейка (`i`, `j`) является соседней по стороне с ячейкой (`i0`, `j0`):

```
i == i0 || j == j0
```

Либо вынести метод изменения соседней ячейки в отдельный метод и вызвать его четыре раза:

```
void modifyCell(char[][] array, int i, int j) {
    if (0 <= i && i < array.length && 0 <= j && j < array[i].length) {
        // любая операция с соседним элементом
        array[i][j]++;
    }
}

// в нужном месте вызываем метод:
modifyCell(array, i0 - 1, j0);
modifyCell(array, i0, j0 - 1);
modifyCell(array, i0, j0 + 1);
modifyCell(array, i0 + 1, j0);
```